# How to run a workflow on user login?

Tags: workflow

Good morning! I have a workflow that does some checks on a user's properties and configures some stuff in the back end, such as creating a group programmatically if it does not already exist.

I am able to test this currently by manually executing the workflow, but is there a way to get the workflow to run automatically when a user accesses the site?

Edit: The workflows are custom - created in Visual Studio and deployed to the site. They do not show up in SharePoint Designer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems risky to me. Running a workflow for each and every login seems like it would put quite a load on the server. Also, if these are resources needed by the user, there is no guarantee that the workflow will actually run at that point in time.

But, if you're using forms auth you could easily create a custom login page and add code to start the workflow as needed.

Another option is to put a web part on the home page that checks if the user needs to have the workflow run and then run it. (it would be important not to run the workflow for each visit to the home page. But this could be workable with perhaps a sharepoint list that stores which users have had the workflow run already, and a cached version of that list in a hashtable in memory to reduce load on the server).

Comment: Unfortunately, I am using claims-auth. Would this still be possible since it's not forms? The site is also meant for an extremely limited number of people - probably 10 max, and not all of which would be on at the same time. I would love to try your recommendation in the last paragraph! Could you point me in the right direction for the part there '[put] web part on the home page [...] and then run it'? I'm not sure where to start with the code...

Comment: So coding is the advanced answer, and there's no "quick" way to get started. Especially since that if this code is written poorly, it could have a negative impact on your site. But if there's only 10 people, then create a survey about area restaurants or whatever, and send them a link to the survey in an email. In the email just say that you want them to see that sharepoint has survey capabilities, and put your workflow on the survey. (or don't use a survey and just create another list that asks them to sign in, or anything. Just get them to populate a list item somehow.)

Comment: Or, since there's just 10 people, just get everything set up for them. You'll probably spend more time creating the workflow and such than just configuring everything for 10 users.

Answer (score 0):

Go to workflow setting --> you will see 3 options under start option in your SPD. Select start automatically when you created. If I got your question.

Comment: These workflows were created and deployed using Visual Studio. Unfortunately, they do not show up in SPD... is that expected?